# Go to a url and click on a button to download a file

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation

I want to download an Excel file from an url.

Unfortunately, I only have the url that contains the "download button", because once I click the button, the url isn't .../file.xls but one, if I go to, will not activate the download process.

Is there were a way with VBA go to this url and click on the button to download the file.

```
Dim IE As InternetExplorer
Sub Test()

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
' You can uncoment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = True

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.navigate "http://webpage.com/"

' Wait while IE loading...
While IE.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Set objInputs = IE.Document.getElementsByTagName("link")

For Each ele In objInputs
    If ele.Title Like "List of control sheets having one or more declared   Then  alert(s)." Then 'Text on the link
        ele.Click
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

However, I think the object I'm aiming at is more like a link than a button, because in the source, there are only several lines of these:

```
<LINK rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="/frm/wdk/theme/documentum/css/webforms.css">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this to access the page using IE:

```
Dim ie As Object
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.application")
With ie
    .Visible = True
    .Navigate ("http://yourlink") 
    While .Busy Or .ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Wend 
End With
```

And then use the command `SendKeys "{TAB}", True` to go to the button and the command `SendKeys "{ENTER}", True` to click on it

Comment: Thanks for answering. How exactly should I use SendKeys "{TAB}", True ? I mean how could I get VBA to know which button I'm talking about ?

Comment: Actually in this case you will need to count manually how many tabs you need to achieve the button focus, you can also use this command ie.Document.All("ButtonID").Click, but you must know the Button's ID value that you see on HTML Source Code

Comment: This is really cool. If for example the location of the center of the button is 3(from left to right) and 5(from bottom to top), how should I write this line of code ?

Comment: If you use the ie.Document.All("ButtonID").Click command I think it is easier, for example
Source Code:<input type="button" id="btnSearch" name="Search">
your code will be like ie.Document.All("btnSearch").Click

Comment: I did a lot of research on your method and posted my code above. Could you take a look please? Regards.

Comment: In your code,there is a loop through all the link objects until you find the object with a specific title, but as you know the title you can go and take href link of this title and use the ie.navigate() command